# Angular.JS: cannot set default route when no hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

**The problem is**: 
I cannot reach home page when url is **www.some.com** but can when it's `www.some.com/#!` or `www.some.com/#!/`

I was define default web app route:

```
$routeProvider.when('', {templateUrl: pathToIncs + 'home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
$routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: pathToIncs + 'home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
```

Added otherwise option:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
```

And turn of html5 mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

As i said befor - it works when I'm came by ulr like **www.some.com/#!** but not when **www.some.com**. In this case **.otherwise** option will be called.

In any other case routing works well. In the my app I got an urls like a www.some.com/#!/login, www.some.com/#!/signup

P.S. Server side works on php5+nginx
P.P.S. I'm use Angular 1.2.0 with ngRoute module

Comment: I can try to solve the problem with `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});`. It's will works, but what should I do with 404 errors in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the < base > tag.

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

Have a route defined for home

```
.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: pathToIncs + 'home.html', 
        controller: 'homeController'
 })
```

using redirectTo on the "/"

```
.when('/', {
    redirectTo: '/home'
})
```

along with the .otherwise

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});
```